Implementing nested loop in Ansible
I wanted to know how to implement nested loop concept to schedule a job in task scheduler which schedules 2 executables,
This is my source yaml
---
scheduledTasks:
# 2 ACTIONS PLEASE CHECK
  - name: random_name
    description: no description
    triggers:
      type: "daily"
      start_boundary: "2022-11-06T12:58:54"
      execution_time_limit: PT4H
      enabled: true
      repetition:
        interval: PT15M
        stop_at_duration_end: false
    run_level: highest
    multiple_instances: 2 #ask
    disallow_start_if_on_batteries: true
    allow_hard_terminate: true
    start_when_available: false
    run_only_if_network_available: false
    allow_demand_start: true
    enabled: true
    hidden: false
    run_only_if_idle: false
    wake_to_run: false
    execution_time_limit: PT4H
    priority: 7
    actions:
      - path: C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.WindowsNotepad_11.2406.9.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\Notepad\Notepad.exe
      - path: C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe

This is my Ansible playbook
---
- name: Schedule a Python script
  hosts: windows_server
  vars_files:
    - /mnt/d/programs/source7.yaml
  tasks:
    - name: Schedule a job from Ansible
      community.windows.win_scheduled_task:
        name: "{{ item.name }}"
        description: "{{ item.description }}"
        actions:
          - path: "{{ item.actions.path }}"
            arguments: "{{ item.action.arguments | default(omit) }}"
        run_level: "{{ item.run_level }}"
        allow_demand_start: "{{ item.allow_demand_start | default(omit) }}"
        multiple_instances: "{{ item.multiple_instances }}"
        disallow_start_if_on_batteries: "{{ item.disallow_start_if_on_batteries | default(omit) }}"
        stop_if_going_on_batteries: "{{ item.stop_if_going_on_batteries | default(omit) }}"
        allow_hard_terminate: "{{ item.allow_hard_terminate }}"
        start_when_available: "{{ item.start_when_available }}"
        run_only_if_network_available: "{{ item.run_only_if_network_available }}"
        run_only_if_idle: "{{ item.run_only_if_idle | default(omit) }}"
        hidden: "{{ item.hidden }}"
        enabled: "{{ item.enabled | default(omit) }}"
        execution_time_limit: "{{ item.execution_time_limit }}"
        wake_to_run: "{{ item.wake_to_run }}"
        priority: "{{ item.priority | default(omit) }}"
        triggers: 
          - type: "{{ item.triggers.type | default(omit) }}"
            start_boundary: "{{ item.triggers.start_boundary }}"
            user_id: "{{ item.triggers.user_id | default(omit) }}"
            enabled: "{{ item.triggers.enabled | default(omit) }}"
            execution_time_limit: "{{ item.triggers.execution_time_limit | default(omit) }}"
            repetition:
              interval: "{{ item.triggers.repetition.interval | default(omit) }}"
              stop_at_duration_end: "{{ item.triggers.repetition.stop_at_duration_end | default(omit) }}"
      loop: "{{ scheduledTasks }}"

I wanted to cycle through the list of paths in actions in the source file and schedule it in the task scheduler,
I've been going through the documents, couldn't find a appropriate solution.
I tried to use with_nested loop, but that doesn't seem appropriate.

Check out ˋwith_subelementsˋ

From your current description it is unclear if you like to schedule one task with two actions (for which you could just provide a list of actions) or if you like to schedule two separate tasks with one action each. Can you also describe in more detail the Parameter: multiple_instances? It there any reason for the question "How to implement nested loop concept to schedule a job in task scheduler which schedules 2 executables?" and focus on a maybe solution?

@U880D I wanted to schedule one task with two actions, as you suggested I used list of actions and it worked, thank you!
I initially thought I had to implement a nested loop to provide an executable path under the actions variable. But parsing the whole list got the job done.
